# Newb Regular Expression Question - Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm pretty new to programming, specifically Ruby and I've been bumping my head working with regular expressions.

What I have is a string such as the following:

```
s = 'Your Product Costs $10.00'
```

What I'm trying to do is write an expression, so my match data is only equal to the price, for example I've been able to do the following.

```
r = /[$]\d....\Z/
```

and therefore

```
match = r.match s
 => #<MatchData "$10.00">
```

My problem is, what if the product price is $100.00 dollars. Well I don't have enough wild cards and my match is nil.

It there away with regular expressions, to say "wild cards until the end of a string?" or "wild cards until [characters]" Or will I have to find the length of a string, find the location of my $ character, and count it out based off each input?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the regexp you want:

```
\$(\d+\.\d+)
```

The ruby code to test:

```
str1 = 'Your Product Costs $10.00'
str2 = 'Your Product Costs $100.00'

regexp = /\$(\d+\.\d+)/

regexp.match str1   # => <MatchData "$10.00" 1:"10.00">
regexp.match str2   # => <MatchData "$100.00" 1:"100.00">
```

The key is to check for the `.` . There's a great website for testing your regular expressions: http://rubular.com/

Comment: I really appreciate the help. Also thanks for the link to rubular, seems like a great little utility that will save me time moving forward.

Comment: Cool, no problem. I use the rubular site almost every time I do something with regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

A regular expression that matches an amount and also ensures that the match is an actual number and not a succession of digits or random characters:

```
/\$([1-9]\d*|0)(\.\d{1,2})?/
```

Matches `$123.1`, `$123.12`, `$123`, `$0.12` etc.

Doesn't match `$01.12`, `$12.` etc.

Further reading: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this?

```
r = /\$\d+\.\d{1,2}/

s = 'Your product costs $10.00'
s2 = 'Your product costs $1000.00'

r.match s
 => #<MatchData "$10.00"> 

r.match s2
 => #<MatchData "$1000.00">
```

It accepts any number of digits before the dot, and one to two digits after the dot. You can change this in the {1, 2} part. Note that if you change it to 0, you have to make the dot optional.

With both the dot and digits after the decimal point optional:

```
r = /\$\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?/

s = "Anything blabla $100060"
r.match s
 => #<MatchData "$100060">"
```

With unlimited number of digits after the decimal point:

```
r = /\$\d+\.\d+/

s = "Product price is: $1560.5215010"
r.match s
 => #<MatchData "$1560.5215010">
```

With unlimited number of digits after the decimal point and optional dot:

```
r = /\$\d+(?:\.\d{1,})?/

s = "Product price is: $1500"
s2 = "Product price is: $19.921501"

r.match s
 => #<MatchData "$1500"> 

r.match s2
 => #<MatchData "$19.921501">
```

Comment: @Alin: Sorry, I fixed that now. Thanks!

Comment: @Thiago You still need to fix `[$]`. If you need to escape `$` use `\$`.

Comment: Wow, great explanations Thiago, really went above be beyond. I truly appreciate the help. This is exactly what I needed to get me moving beyond reading documentation. Seriously, thanks a ton.

Comment: @Alin Thanks again! :-) However, I think your regex is better anyway. +1 Although it will depend on asker's needs.

Comment: `[\d?]+` matches one or more digits or question marks.  The regex for *any number of digits including zero* is `\d*`.  Also, you should treat the dot and the trailing digits as an atomic unit like @Alin did: `(?:\.\d+)?`.  Your way incorrectly matches a "number" that ends with a dot, e.g. `12.`.  (p.s., I know this question is old, but I missed it the first time around, and those errors needed to be addressed.)

Comment: @Alan Yep, that's why I edited it. I thought about people coming from search engines and then resolved to change it. My expertise in regexes is very poor. I'm going to update with your suggestions now. Thank you.